# How to get 30 days prior to current date?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a start calendar input box and an end calendar input box. We want defaults start calendar input box 30 days prior to current date and the end calendar input box to be the current date. Here is my date vars.

```
var today = new Date(),
    dd    = today.getDate(),
    mm    = today.getMonth(),
    yyyy  = today.getFullYear(),
    month = ["January", "February", "March",
        "April", "May", "June", "July", "August",
        "September", "October" "November", "December"],
    startdate = month[mm] + ", " + yyyy.toString();
```

The end date would be something like `var enddate = startdate - 30;` Obviously this won't work.

So if the current date is December 30, 2011 I'd want the start date to read December 1, 2011.

EDIT: My question was answered... sort of. `Date.today();` and `Date.today().add(-30);` work but I need the date in the format of `January 13, 2012`. Not `Fri Jan 13 2012 10:48:56 GMT -055 (EST)`. Any help?

MORE EDIT: As of this writing it's 2018. Just use [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/). It's the best.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/563406/add-days-to-datetime-using-java-script I think that might help.

Answer (score 172, accepted):

Try using the excellent [Datejs JavaScript date library](http://www.datejs.com/) (the original is no longer maintained so you may be interested in [this actively maintained fork](https://github.com/abritinthebay/datejs) instead):

```
Date.today().add(-30).days(); // or...
Date.today().add({days:-30});
```

**[Edit]**

See also the excellent [Moment.js JavaScript date library](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/subtract/):

```
moment().subtract(30, 'days'); // or...
moment().add(-30, 'days');
```

Comment: I was struggling to get the start and end dates 30 days before and after today in UTC without the time. This worked: `moment( moment().subtract(30, 'days') ).format("YYYY-MM-DD")`

Comment: I used the `moment()` approach and appended the `toDate()` method to get back the JavaScript date object. Thanks!

Comment: Why would you need to use a library for this? That seems crazy.

Comment: can you recommend a library for console.log ?

Comment: The first answer doesn't work check this link instead https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563406/add-days-to-javascript-date

Answer (score 237):

To subtract days from a JS Date object you can use the `setDate()` method, along with the date to start the calculation from. This will return an epoch timestamp as an integer, so to convert this to a Date you'll need to again provide it to the `Date()` object constructor. The final example would look like this:

```js
var today = new Date();
var priorDate = new Date(new Date().setDate(today.getDate() - 30));

console.log(today)
console.log(priorDate);
```

Comment: Without using an external library I like this solution the best. Thanks.

Comment: Note that this method returns in Javascript Timestamp format. To convert it back to date object, you need to pass the above to `new Date(priorDate)`

Comment: Sometimes you just want vanilla js without a library! Thanks :)

Comment: I get setDate() is not a function

Comment: @chovy the only way I can imagine you're getting that error is because you're not calling `setDate()` on a `Date` object. It's impossible to diagnose without seeing your code, though.

Answer (score 111):

Here's an ugly solution for you:

```
var date = new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() - 30));
```

Comment: Agreed - this is the best solution.  This is *exactly* the solution of Rory McCrossan's answer - but concise, and complete (no external libraries required).

Answer (score 51):

```
startDate = new Date(today.getTime() - 30*24*60*60*1000);
```

The `.getTime()` method returns a standard JS timestamp (milliseconds since Jan 1/1970) on which you can use regular math operations, which can be fed back to the Date object directly.

Answer (score 15):

**Get next 30th day from today**

```js
let now = new Date()
console.log('Today: ' + now.toUTCString())
let next30days = new Date(now.setDate(now.getDate() + 30))
console.log('Next 30th day: ' + next30days.toUTCString())
```

**Get last 30th day form today**

```js
let now = new Date()
console.log('Today: ' + now.toUTCString())
let last30days = new Date(now.setDate(now.getDate() - 30))
console.log('Last 30th day: ' + last30days.toUTCString())
```

Answer (score 8):

Javascript can handle it without any external libraries.

```js
var today = new Date();
var dateLimit = new Date(new Date().setDate(today.getDate() - 30));

document.write(today + "<br/>" + dateLimit)
```

Answer (score 7):

Simple 1 liner **Vanilla Javascript** code :

```
const priorByDays = new Date(Date.now() - days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
```

For example:
`days = 7`
Assume current `date = Fri Sep 18 2020 01:33:26 GMT+0530`

**The result would be : `Fri Sep 11 2020 01:34:03 GMT+0530`**

> *The beauty of this is you can manipulate it to get result in desired type*

- timestamp : `Date.now() - days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000`
- ISOString: `new Date(Date.now() - 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000).toISOString()`

Answer (score 6):

Easy.`(Using Vanilla JS)`

```
let days=30;
this.maxDateTime = new Date(Date.now() - days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
```

ISOFormat ?

```
let days=30;
this.maxDateTime = new Date(Date.now() - days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000).toISOString();
```

Answer (score 5):

`let today = new Date()`

`let last30Days = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate() - 30)`

`last30Days` will be in Date Object

Answer (score 4):

I will prefer **moment js**

```
startDate = moment().subtract(30, 'days').format('LL')  // January 29, 2015

endDate = moment().format('LL'); // February 28, 2015
```

Answer (score 2):

I use [date.js](http://www.datejs.com/). It handles this easily and takes care of all the leap-year nastiness.

Answer (score 2):

This is an ES6 version

```
let date = new Date()
let newDate = new Date(date.setDate(date.getDate()-30))
console.log(newDate.getMonth()+1 + '/' + newDate.getDate() + '/' + newDate.getFullYear() )
```

Comment: How is this different from any of the other answers, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31665235)? Also, there's nothing here that couldn't have been done in ES5... or ES3 even.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that simply through 1 line of code using moment in Node JS. :)

```
    let lastOneMonthDate = moment().subtract(30,"days").utc().toISOString()
```

Don't want UTC format, EASIER :P

```
    let lastOneMonthDate = moment().subtract(30,"days").toISOString()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't inclined to momentjs, you can use this:

`let x = new Date()`

`x.toISOString(x.setDate(x.getDate())).slice(0, 10)`

Basically it gets the current date (numeric value of date of current month) and then sets the value. Then it converts into ISO format from which I slice down the pure numeric date (i.e. 2019-09-23)

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking for the format 'dd month yyyy', here's what worked for me:

```
let date = new Date()

let newDate = new Date(date.setDate(date.getDate()-30))

console.log(newDate.getDate()+ ' ' +newDate.toLocaleString('default', {month: 'long'}) + ' ' + newDate.getFullYear() )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use moment.js

```
let startDate =  moment().subtract(30, "days").format('YYYY-MM-DD'); //2021-05-18
let endDate = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'); //2021-06-17
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let currentDate = new Date()
let pastDate = new Date(currentDate.getTime() - (30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)); // 30 days
```