# Mongoose delete by timestamp

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have my mongoose model:

```
LogSchema = new Schema({
    level : String,
    code: String,
    message: String,
    Timestamp : { 
      type : Date, 
      default: Date.now 
    }
})
```

I'm trying to delete all documents older than 30 days (Timestamp field) using this code:

```
var d = new Date();
var older_than = new Date(d.setDate(d.getDate() - 30));
Log.remove({ Timestamp : {$lte : older_than } }, function(err) {
    if (!err) {
        console.log("Clean complete")
    } else {
        console.log("Clean error")
    }
});
```

I see on console: "Clean complete", but I still have all documents older than 30 days.

Something wrong in my code?

Comment: What version of mongoose are you using?

Comment: mongoose version: ^5.0.10

Comment: Is the date stored as an actual timestamp in your db? i.e: 
`1520699330307`. If so, the value of `older_than` is incorrect as its a date object and not a timestamp. Do `console.log(older_than)` and check it out.

Comment: To get a timestamp from a date object, you can do `older_than.valueOf()`

Comment: i have updated the answer. it is working for me and may also work for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better you try as below using [moment.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment)

```
var moment = require('moment');
var older_than = moment().subtract(30, 'days').toDate();
Log.find({ Timestamp: { $lte: older_than } }).remove().exec().then((RemoveStatus) => {
    console.log("Documents Removed Successfully");
}).catch((err) => {
    console.error('something error');
    console.error(err);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Moment is not at all required here. It's a lot of bloat which basically forks the base Date and adds to it.

Instead try this:

```
const thirtyDaysAgo = new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() - 30));

try {
  const { deletedCount } = await Log.deleteMany({ Timestamp: { $lte: thirtyDaysAgo } }).exec()
  console.log(deletedCount, "Logs since", thirtyDaysAgo, "have been cleared")
} catch(e) {
    console.error(e.message)
}
```

Source: [How to get 30 days prior to current date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8842732/how-to-get-30-days-prior-to-current-date)

If you don't need it to be 30 days, but a month ago instead, you can do this too:

```
const sameDayLastMonth = new Date(new Date().setMonth(new Date().getMonth() - 1))

try {
  const { deletedCount } = await Log.deleteMany({ Timestamp: { $lte: thirtyDaysAgo } }).exec()
  console.log(deletedCount, "Logs since", sameDayLastMonth, "have been cleared")
} catch(e) {
    console.error(e.message)
}
```

Source: my head =D.

The 2 things you were missing:

1. `.getDate()` & `.setDate()` will return a number, which then needs to be constructed as a new Date.
2. You should use [.deleteMany()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mongoose-deletemany-function/?ref=lbp) instead of .remove(), to be sure more than one are removed.

Also note, the pattern find().remove() found in the accepted answer isn't required.