# how to get what date was 4 years 5 months 3 days ago with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have 3 input text

1. `<input class="form-control" id="year" name="year" type="text">`
2. `<input class="form-control" id="month" name="month" type="text">`
3. `<input class="form-control" id="day" name="day" type="text">`

I know how to get 4 years ago, or 5 month ago or 3 days ago..
but how to combine three of them?

Comment: please elaborate the question properly and what you wanted as a output

Comment: how to combine them means you want 4 years+5month+3days back date ?

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+find+date+days+months+years+ago+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get 30 days prior to current date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8842732/how-to-get-30-days-prior-to-current-date)

Comment: Getting the data of 4 years ago has nothing to deal with dom. please add more detail to your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach using the built-in Date object. We create a new Date object representing the current date, and then use the `setFullYear()` and `setMonth()` methods to subtract the specified number of years and months, respectively, and then use `setDate()` method to subtract the specified number of days

```js
const getPreviousDate = (years, months, days) => {
    const date = new Date();
    date.setFullYear(date.getFullYear() - years);
    date.setMonth(date.getMonth() - months);
    date.setDate(date.getDate() - days);

    return date;
};


console.log(getPreviousDate(1, 2, 10));
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you wanted to deduct the year,month and day from current date?
If yes, use date-fns.

```js
var sub = require('date-fns/sub')
var date = new Date()

var newDate = sub(date, {
  years: 5,
  months: 4,
  days: 2
}))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/date-fns@2.29.3/index.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your script is not runnable here. OP would need to know how to make modules too

Comment: If you use a code snippet, be sure you test wether your code actually runs. The snippet you gave jist gives « script error ». Not very helpful to the OP.